# Can anybody provide simple steps of "Skeleton Pruning by Contour Partitioning with Discrete Curve Evolution" Algorithm

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

Can anybody provide simple steps of "Skeleton Pruning by Contour Partitioning with Discrete Curve Evolution" Algorithm

or c++ code i have document if some one is familiar simple steps of the algorithm

Answer (score 1):

1. Google "Skeleton Pruning by Contour Partitioning with Discrete Curve Evolution"
2. Download the paper and read it. Authors are Xiang Bai, Longin Jan Latecki, Wen-yu Liu
3. If you haven't already figured out the algorithm by reading the paper, contact the authors for code.

Comment: Matlab code should be fairly readable for someone skilled with c++

Comment: Did anyone manage to get that code to work? I can only get the contours of my image, and can't get any skeleton image